# Hide schemas (tables,views,etc under schema) from users

Tags: sql-server, schema, access-control

I want users not to be able to see the objects under a schema , as well as the schema. I have denied their access to all these objects on select, update, etc, which is successful. Hence they can’t view the data or work with it! But they still can see the the name of the objects in the object explorer. I want to only see the objects they have access to, not the ones they don’t.

Many thanks for your help.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: See how toi grant users.

Comment: @bigtheo I didn’t understand ur question

Comment: I would Say see users privilegies.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, as mentioned in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281467/5059085):

> There is No `HIDE` feature in SQL Server instead, you can Deny the permission to that Table for Certain Users of User Groups...

The only thing you may be able to do is globally hide the objects for everyone, via extended properties, as discussed in the article [Hiding tables in SSMS Object Explorer](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/04/03/hiding-tables-in-ssms-object-explorer-using-extended-properties/).

Example code for hiding the object:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

Example code for unhiding it:

```
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

This is probably a terrible idea to do in a production server though, from a management perspective.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server automatically trims catalog queries (like `select * from sys.tables`) based on the user's permissions.

The ability to view the metadata on an object is controlled by the VIEW DEFINITION permissions.  The VIEW DEFINITION permission is implied by any *other* permissions unless denied.

So this:

> want to only see the objects they have access to, not the ones they don’t.

Is the behavior if you make sure to grant *no access* to the other objects.  If they can see the objects, they have been granted VIEW DEFINITION on the object.  Could be directly, or on the schema or the database, or the permissions might have been added to the PUBLIC role.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The users have access to database, since they need to have access to particular schema. However it is the schemas which they won’t be having access to under the database that I would to be not seen in the object explorer. I’ve tryed denying the view definition on the schema to the user, however they can still see the table names , view names under the schema

Comment: Please create and post a simplified repro of the issue in your question body.  You're missing something.

Comment: the users are added via the windows Active Directory security group. Is that the hindrance ?